# Using sortable.js with HTML custom data attribute

Tags: javascript, html, sorting, sortablejs

How does one use HTML's custom data attribute to sort items using sortable.js?

Or how does one define custom sorting parameter using sortable.js?

For example in the code below, I'd like to sort with data-timestamp

```
<ul id="items">
    <li data-timestamp='1'>item Y</li>
    <li data-timestamp='2'>item B</li>
    <li data-timestamp='3'>item Z</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `store` feature documented here: https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable#store

You can pass Sortable a sorted array of the attributes, and set the `dataIdAttr` to `'data-timestamp'`

```
Sortable.create(el, {
    dataIdAttr: 'data-timestamp',
    store: {
        get: function () {
            return ['1', '2', '3'];
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks @owen-m, I believe this works. However, it doesn't seem to affect newly appended items. Here is a jsbin to showcase the problem
https://jsbin.com/gonuhupixo/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Also @owen-m, please explain what the get:function() does in your code above

Comment: @DamilolaBoiyelove If you want it to affect newly appended items you must call `get` yourself by using `sortableInstance.sort(sortableInstance,options.store.get())`.

It works by taking the returned array, which should be an array of values for the specified `dataIdAttr`, and sorting the elements in the order specified in that array.